# Problems with terminating loop at specific time

Tags: c++, for-loop, command-line

Having trouble with my loop. The program is supposed to resemble a print out of a 
lotto ticket. The user enters in how many sets of lotto numbers he/she wants. Each line is labeled alphabetically, yet if someone wants more then ten lines (letter J) of lotto numbers the program is supposed to start back over at A again.  My problem is that if anyone enters 10 (or any interval of ten) "mega" gets printed like so:

[image]

"Mega" should only be printed again if there is another line of lotto numbers.
In "int main()" inside the "for()" is my attempt to remedy this problem.

```
#include <iostream> //I/O
#include <iomanip> //setw
#include <ctime>  //seeding srand
#include <string> //size
#define RAND(a,b) (a+rand()% (b-a+1))
#define die(errmsg) {cerr << errmsg << endl; exit(1);}
using namespace std;

/*
  Author: Zachary Stow
  Date: July/20/15
  Homework #5
  Objective: To design a program that imitates the print out
             of a lottery ticket.
*/

//********************************fillup()********************************
void fillup(int lotto[], int n, int from, int to)
{ 
    void bubble_sort(int x[], int n);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        lotto[i] = RAND(from,to);
    }
    bubble_sort(lotto,5);
}

//*****************************bubble_sort()******************************
void bubble_sort(int x[], int n)   
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        int temp;

        for(int j=i+1; j<n ; j++)
        {
            if(x[i] > x[j])
            {
                temp = x[i];
                x[i] = x[j];
                x[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }        
}


//********************************print()*********************************
void print(int x[], int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {       
        cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << x[i] <<" ";
    }
    cout <<" ";
    cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << RAND(1,46);  
    cout << endl;
}

//********************************isNumber********************************
bool isNumber(string str)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
    {
        if(!isdigit(str[i]))return(false);
    }

    return(true);
}

//**********************************check*********************************
void check(int argc, char **argv)   
{
    bool isNumber(string);

    if(argc != 2)die("usage: megaMillion number_tickets");

    string num_tickets = argv[1];
    if(!isNumber(num_tickets))die("Not a digit.");  //removed num_tickets for now

    int num;
    num = atoi(num_tickets.c_str());    
    if(num <= 0)die("Zero or negative number.");    //doesnt work
}

//*********************************printmega()****************************
void printmega(int letter)
{
    if(letter == 65)
        {
            cout << endl;
            cout <<"                  Mega" << endl; //10 you get a mega
        }  
}

//*********************************main()*********************************
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    void fillup(int x[], int n, int from, int to);
    void print(int x[], int n);
    void check(int argc, char **argv); 
    void printmega(int letter);

    check(argc, argv);
    srand(time(NULL));                   

    cout <<"                  Mega" << endl;   

    int letter = 65;

    for(int i = 0; i < atoi(argv[1]); i++)
    {
        if(i == atoi(argc[1]))cout << "Hi"; //my attempt to stop the loop from printing
                                            //only mega after J
        cout <<(char)letter++;              //when theres no more lines
        cout <<"  ";

        if(letter == 75)letter = 65;

        int lotto[5];

        fillup(lotto,5,1,56);                     

        print(lotto,5);

        printmega(letter); 
    }

    return(0);                  
}
```

Comment: When posting try to create a minimal example which still demonstrates your problem.  In this question we don't really need to know how you implemented your bubble sort.

Comment: This seems similar to the problem of outputting elements in a list seperated by commas. The naive approaches either print a comma, a space and the element or print the element, a comma and a space. The first is no good because the first element has a comma before it. The second, because there's a comma after the last element. In that case, the fix is to print a comma and a space _IF_ this is not the first element, _THEN_ print just an element. This is also natural and the way we draw a list on paper.I imagine the same approach would wash your problems away. ;)

Comment: note that you have a typo in your "attempt to stop the loop" argc is an integer, you probably meant argv[1] or just write `if ( (i%10) == 0 ) ...` since ten is a fixed limit in your program.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem I would choose to use two nested loops, here is a minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  double aValues[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 6, 2};
  int nTotalLines = sizeof(aValues)/sizeof(double);
  int nLinesPerBlock = 5;

  int nLineNumber = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i <= nTotalLines/nLinesPerBlock
      && nLineNumber < nTotalLines; ++i)
  {
    std::cout << "Start of block..." << std::endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < nLinesPerBlock && nLineNumber < nTotalLines; ++j)
    {
      std::cout << "  Number: " << aValues[nLineNumber++] << std::endl;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

You will need to adapt this code to fit your problem.  It is not necessary to use nested loops but to me it seems more logical (you cycle one outer loop for each block and one inner loop for each line).

Another tip:  Make use of variables so you don't need to keep typing things like `atoi(argv[1])`, instead create a variable `int name = atoi(argv[1]);` and use `name` wherever you need it.